# setOnCreatePreferencesChangeListener Type Mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

My kotlin fragment class:

```
class OptionsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.options, rootKey)
        val contact = findPreference("contact_developer")
        contact.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }
```

The `this` in `contact.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this)` is underlined red and showing this error:

```
Type Mismatch. 
Required: Preferences.OnPreferenceChangeListener!
Found: OptionsFragment
```

My fragment clearly implements `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` so why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right `OnPreferenceChangeListener` imported?

Comment: Only one is suggested: https://i.imgur.com/qcj0FQE.png

Comment: Oh, yeah, the right `Preference`, then. If you're using the old support libraries, it should be `android.support.v7.preference.Preference`. If you're using androidx, it's `androidx.preference.Preference`.

Comment: Yeah it's not letting me import it: https://i.imgur.com/S6USzkk.png

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using androidx, though. You've got `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` right below that.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. "Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX..." seems to be the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation is wrong

implement `Preferences.OnPreferenceChangeListener` instead of `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`

Comment: I am using the androidx `Preference` library so I want to implement this: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html however it is not coming up in my idea when I type `Preference.On...`